# How large is the Edge?

Tags: edge-chronicles

There are various maps of the titular Edge in the Edge Chronicles. However, they don't seem to have Earth units, so I've realized that we don't really know how big it is. Country-sized, or continent-sized? Is going from Sanctaphrax to the Deepwoods like going from London to Paris, Egypt to Nigeria, or Australia to Portugal?

How large is the Edge? That is, how far is it from Sanctaphrax to Riverrise, how wide is the Edge at Riverrise, and how rapidly does it narrow? Can we determine anything from sky galleon flight times, walking times, etc?